# Reading a Text File in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, .net

I have a list of words that I'd like to read into a list of strings.  I'm having some trouble implementing this in a metro app with the `Windows Runtime`

[image]

Normally I'd use the follow code:

```vb
'load text file in to word list
Using sr As New StreamReader(filePath)
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        WordList.Add(sr.ReadLine.Trim)
    Loop
End Using
```

I'm trying to use the code from [The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)

```vb
Dim folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
folder = folder.GetFolderAsync("Data")
Dim file = folder.GetFileAsync("WordList.txt")
Dim readFile = Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file)
```

But it gets tripped up on the second line and I wouldn't know what to do with it even if it didn't.  I've killed the `Await` keyword because for some reason it can't see the `Async` attribute on the `GetFolder` method.

Comment: Please clarify the last line in your question. 1) "It gets tripped up" is too vague. Is there an error? What is the error? 2) You mention an attribute, but you never actually show how you are using it.

Comment: The second line throws the following `InvalidCastException`: `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFolder'"`  I get a compiler error when using the Await keyword.  The article I linked to shows using the `Await` keyword and also has the pretty much the same code I've posted, so I'm not sure what's breaking between its implementation and mine.

Comment: To put it simply, you must use `await` in this case. If not, you will get the errors you mention above. In regards to the error you see when using `await`, it is likely that the signature for the method (`GetFolder`?) that contains the `await` code is not correct. I cannot be more specific about the error because you have not included the method signature above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [File Access Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) application from the Windows Store App Dev Center

```vb
Private Async Function LoadWords() As Task
    Dim fileName As String = "WordListComma.txt"
    Dim fileContent As String = ""
    Dim file As StorageFile
    Dim numBytesLoaded As UInt32
    Dim size As UInt64

    file = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName)

    If file Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception(String.Format("Could not find file {0}", fileName))

    Using readStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
        Using dataReader As New DataReader(readStream)
            size = readStream.Size
            If size <= UInt32.MaxValue Then
                numBytesLoaded = Await dataReader.LoadAsync(CType(size, UInt32))
                fileContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

Also the `Await` keyword must be used when calling `Async` functions and also can only exist inside of methods that themselves have been decorated with the `Async` keyword, so it needed to get added to the LoadWords() signature.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to your question. If this is related to your question, you should add the contents above (in your question text) instead of here (as an answer). Furthermore, it is unclear to me what is wrong with the `LoadWords` code. (Again, you are saying "it doesn't work", and you don't give any specifics). It actually does read the file contents when I try it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for me to add here.  My question was how to read a file using WinRT.  This code does exactly that and provides an external link to more samples.

Comment: I was unclear if this solved your problem (it is an answer to your question), or if there is something wrong with this code (you say it doesn't work). If it is indeed the former, then I'm glad it solved your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I edited the post to make it more clear that the insturctions regarding `Await` were solutions to what *was* the problem, but is fixed in the posted code.  This did solve my, and hopefully future SO'rs, inquieries.